# How to get an entity's key when using django-nonrel on App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models, django-nonrel

I'm using `django-nonrel` (http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) on Google App Engine. I have my models etc. setup and everything works great. I had one question though. I want to be able to access an entity's key. Given a model named 'Review', I do `Review.objects.get(pk = 1).key()` which throws an error (`AttributeError`).

Is there any way I can get the given entity's key so that I can use it instead of being forced to use the pk/id? I want to use the key as a unique identifier for unique & secret URLS (if someone has a better suggestion to achieve this, I'm all ears).

Comment: Although keys might be *unguessable* at a glance, they should by no means be considered *secret*, maybe consider storing [SHA1 hashes](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) of some unique part on your entities to use in your 'secret' URLs

Comment: `1` isn't a key - it's an ID, which is only part of a key.

Comment: The two answers below don't seem to work. Rishabh - Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can get id by calling object.key().id() which returns a unique key inside python .In templates you can simply call object.key.id . Then you can use [get_by_id](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_id) to get the object

Comment: This does not seem to work with `django-nonrel`. I'm instead taking what Chris said into note and generating SHA1 hashes based on a unique string.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your primary key on django-nonrel from the meta data:

review._meta.pk

or for key name:
key=getattr(review,review._meta.pk.column)

Apparently the 'id' field changes depending whether your on the dev or production server.  So this works!

reference:
http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/04/working-models/

Comment: The primary key is not the same as the GAE key.